# As in SharePoint site case can we control external sharing per MS Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, microsoft-teams, external-sharing, guest-access

Inside SharePoint we can enable and disable external sharing per site (whether classic, Team-connected or communication sites), as follow:

[image]

But inside MS Teams seems we can only have an org-wide setting for either enable/disable external and guest access for ALL the MS Teams, but we do not have control per MS Team? is my observation correct?

here is the MS Team setting to control external and guess access:

[image]

So let say we have 2 MS Teams; TeamsA & TeamsB. Then can we disable external sharing inside TeamsA while enable it inside TeamsB??

So in TeamsA you can not invite external users to any chat while you can do so in TeamsB? now in SharePoint we can disable external sharing for the related SharePoint site while enable inside the other site, so this is supported inside SharePoint but not inside MS Teams?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. Underlying Teams is the Microsoft 365 Group. Group allow list is global, i.e. you can allow any domain or specific domains to be added to any M365 Group. There is also a deny list if you want to go that route.

These are set in Azure AD at https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/UserSettings.

SharePoint has separate settings. You can set the allow/deny list on a per-site basis. This means in theory someone could be a member of the M365 Group, but have no access to the SPO site files.

https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/solutions/collaborate-in-site?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so in short.. sharepoint support define external sharing per site, while office 365 group does NOT support defining external sharing per group?